# Hiding a foreground UNNotificationAction on watchOS

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch, unusernotificationcenter

My scenario:

I have an app that sends push notifications about articles on a daily basis. The iOS app has three UNNotificationActions attached to the notification -- one to read the article, one to share the article, and one to save the article for later. The read/share article actions are foreground actions, while the save article action happens in the background.

I also have a watchOS version of the app that displays a few top stories, with an option to save for later in the iOS app.

My issue is this: I only want the watch to display the save article background action. The other two UNNotificationActions don't apply to the watchOS app (and wouldn't make sense). Is there a way to hide those two action on the watch? I figured it would be easy, but I don't see any easy way to do this, so I feel like I must be missing something obvious...

For example, the News app has three notification actions on iOS, two foreground actions. On watchOS, only one background action shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you've managed to solve this on your own, but since `watchOS 5.0` you have access to `WKUserNotificationInterfaceController`'s

`// notificationActions can only be changed once didReceiveNotification: has been called
    @available(watchOS 5.0, *)
    open var notificationActions: [UNNotificationAction]`

As the comment states you can remove your iOS specific actions inside your `func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification` implementation.

Answer (score -1):

My solution next:

```
- (void)didReceiveNotification:(UNNotification *)notification {
  [super didReceiveNotification:notification];
  self.notificationActions = nil;
}
```